# SQL Executing Order by and Group by together

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table

```
UNIQUEKEY    ID      Clicks IsProcessed   INSERTDATE
 1         100001   10        1         2011-05-14 00:00:00.000
 2         100001   20        0         2011-05-13 00:00:00.000
 3         100001   30        1         2011-05-18 00:00:00.000
 4         100002   10        1         2011-05-20 00:00:00.000
 5         100002   15        0         2011-05-24 00:00:00.000
 6         100002   10        0         2011-05-05 00:00:00.000
```

I need a T-SQL query which will first Order by INSERTDATE (desc)
Once ordered it should return me a GROUP by on ID and IsProcessed and the result should display ALL columns Orderby and grouped by as described above.

EDIT :
So If we run the query for lets say `ID 10001` it should give me 2 result sets :
Desired Result :

```
UNIQUEKEY    ID      Clicks IsProcessed   INSERTDATE
 3         100001   30        1         2011-05-18 00:00:00.000
 1         100001   10        1         2011-05-14 00:00:00.000        
 2         100001   20        0         2011-05-13 00:00:00.000
```

Reson being `ID` and `IsProcessed` are serving as a key and the Result is sorted by `Date (desc)`.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: can you add the desired result?

Comment: Isn't it like this? `SELECT * FROM tableNAME ORDER BY ID, IsProcessed, INSERTDATE Desc`?

Comment: This doesn't involve a GROUP BY.  There is no aggregation.  It's just an ORDER BY.  If you want the IsProcessed=1 first, change @JohnWoo's query to have IsProcessed DESC.  If you really want two resultsets you can leave IsProcessed out of the ORDER BY and have one SELECT with IsProcessed=1 and another with IsProcessed=0.

Comment: @GilM I agree, Using `GROUP BY` involves using `AGGREGATE FUNCTION`.

Comment: Any *single* query (outside of weird, deprecated features) will produce a *single* result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @ID int = 100001
declare @IsProcessed int

declare
  crsMy cursor fast_forward for
select
  distinct IsProcessed
from
  tTest
order by
  IsProcessed desc

open crsMy

fetch next from crsMy into @IsProcessed

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  select
    UNIQUEKEY
    ,ID
    ,Clicks
    ,IsProcessed
    ,INSERTDATE
  from
    tTest
  where
    (ID=@ID)
    and
    (IsProcessed=@IsProcessed)
  order by
    INSERTDATE desc



  fetch next from crsMy into @IsProcessed
end

close crsMy
deallocate crsMy
```

or on [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0451d/4/0)

(on sqlfiddle is only the first result set displayed.)

Comment: What problem are you solving that John Woo's query doesn't??

Comment: "So If we run the query for lets say ID 10001, it should give me 2 result sets"

Comment: Sorry for the doubling... @RichardTheKiwi: "So If we run the query for lets say ID 10001, **it should give me 2 result sets**". Nothing else is different, just as there are different values ​​in the 'IsProcessed' field, my answer create a exact amount of result set.